# How to fade in and out text and css using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, delay, fadein, fadeout

What i want to do is change the text and the css of a div for a specific amount of time by fading in and out the next text and css.

When the form gets submitted, i want to add a class to the div, fade in the css and the new text which is 'Number successfully added' for about 3 secs, then fade out that text and remove the css and put the old text back in its place.

My div that would contain the text and needs to have a class added to it is

```
<div id="form_result"></div>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work...maybe the logic is wrong.

```
$('#form_result').html('<h3>Number successfully added!!</h3>').addClass('form_result').fadeIn('fast').delay(1500).fadeOut('fast').removeClass('form_result').html('<h3>Please enter a number:</h3>');
```

Comment: its works on my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KfuAr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below js. It works fine in JSfiddle.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/KfuAr/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="main_div">
    <span id="form_result"><h3>Please enter a number</h3></span>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="fade_function();" value="Click" />
```

JS

```
function fade_function()
{
    $("#form_result").html("<h3>Number successfully added!!<h3>");
    $('#main_div').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000, function(){
        $("#form_result").html("<h3>Please enter a number</h3>");  
    });
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want to do but in the animate I want to have this style "border: 5px solid #FFF;background: #A7FC7C;" but also after the 3 seconds I want to animate the css being removed

Comment: You can apply css or addClass using jquery as $("#form_result").addClass("form_result"). Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KfuAr/2/

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $("#form_result").hide()
    $(this).before("<span class='msg'>Number successfully added!!</span>");
    $('.msg').fadeOut(1500);
    $("#form_result").fadeIn(1500)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkce8/

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Ideally I would liek to fade out one message before fading in the other

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display what is in

```
<div id="form_result"></div>
```

back?

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bH4Jn/)